# Want to Add Dialog(Another Activity) when menu item selected

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-menu

I want to add dialog when men item selected my the use please link me some tutorial or something which help me out in my query..!!

Thank you for your kind time.. :)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case GO_ITEM_ID :
          //See i want to add menu item here but please tell me how.
        return true;
    case CLEAR_ITEM_ID :

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why System.exit(0)? That is nasty, use finish();

Comment: I'm confused...have you added the menu items `GO`, `CLEAR`, etc... to your `menu` folder? Or that is what you need help with?

Comment: Do you want to show a dialog (as the question states) or add a menu item (as the code comments say)?

Comment: @codeMagic i just want that when i click on this GO_ITEM_ID (Button on Action bar) then a dialog(Another Activity) will pop up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go to an `Activity` then you simply use an `Intent` as you would any other time. Something like

```
@Override
```

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case GO_ITEM_ID :
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, NextActivityName.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

If you want it to have the appearance of a `Dialog` then simply add this line

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

to that `<acitvity>` tag in your `manifest`.